# Get xml child elements from parent via button to new form

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-ce

I have an xml file with the following info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <AssessmentForm title="MACHINE-NAME Assessment">
    <Title>MACHINE-NAME Assessment</Title>
    <AssessmentSections>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_ONE" sectionGroupID="0">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_1</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="0">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_TWO" sectionGroupID="1">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_2</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="1">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
      <AssessmentSection sectionNameID="SECTION_THREE" sectionGroupID="2">
        <SectionName>SECTION_NUMBER_2</SectionName>
        <SectionDescription>Description of Section to go here</SectionDescription>
        <SectionItems>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_ONE" itemID="0" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item One</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_TWO" itemID="1" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item Two</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
          <SectionItem itemNameID="ITEM_THREE" itemID="2" itemGroupID="2">
            <ItemName>Item Three</ItemName>
            <Significance>Description of Item to go here</Significance>
            <Result />
          </SectionItem>
        </SectionItems>
      </AssessmentSection>
    </AssessmentSections>
</AssessmentForm>
```

I have managed to get child elements using LINQ, by doing the following:

```
var menu = (from m in doc.Root.Descendants("AssessmentSections").Descendants("AssessmentSection")
                    select new
                    {
                        sectionID = Convert.ToInt32(m.Attribute("sectionGroupID").Value),
                        sectionName = m.Attribute("sectionNameID").Value,
                        sectionItems = (from sub in doc.Descendants("SectionItems").Descendants("SectionItem")
                                        where Convert.ToInt32(sub.Attribute("itemGroupID").Value).Equals(Convert.ToInt32(m.Attribute("sectionGroupID").Value))
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            itemGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(sub.Attribute("itemGroupID").Value),
                                            itemID = Convert.ToInt32(sub.Attribute("itemID").Value),
                                            itemName = sub.Element("ItemName").Value,
                                            itemResult = sub.Element("Result").Value
                                        }).ToArray()
                    }).ToArray();
```

My problem however is to get the correct child elements for the correct parent. My current code:

```
foreach (var m in menu)
            {
                //display m in button array
            }
            foreach (var sub in m.sectionItems)
            {
                //display sub in textbox & combobox array
            }
```

My question, how would I get all the child items from ONLY SECTION 1 to display when I click on SECTION 1 buttton, same for child elements of the other sections also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I got the result using:

```
foreach (var m in menu)
            {
                //display button array
            }
            foreach (var sectionItem in m.sectionItems.Where(x => x.itemGroupID == m.sectionID))
            {
                //display sub in textbox & combobox array
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add check on node's attribute value.

For example for getting Section 1 only this should work:

```
var section1 = (from m in doc.Root.Descendants("AssessmentSections").Descendants("AssessmentSection")
                where m.Attribute("sectionNameID").Value == "SECTION_ONE"
                select m);
```

Comment: Thanks. This I got in the bag. But remember "SECTION_ONE" should be a variable. Basically, the Where clause should be something like, 
where m.Attribute("sectionGroupID").Value == sub.itemGroupID
I cannot seem to pair the "sectionID" from menu with "itemGroupID" from sectionItems

Comment: @BennyTheunis you can pass any value using variable

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. I still don't get the right child elements thrown out, when the parent menu button is clicked. However, When I use "SECTION_ONE", I do get Section 1's items, but then it will show Section 1 items for all the parent menus. I'm not 100% sure how to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement sectionOne = doc.Descendants(namespace + "AssessmentSection").First(x => x.Attribute("sectionNameID").Value.Equals("SECTION_ONE"));
        IEnumerable<XElement> elements = sectionOne.Elements(namespace + "SectionItem");

        foreach (XElement element in elements) 
        {
            //Do something
        }
```

I did something like this, hope it helps